# Convertir cadena de texto en array anidado en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo varias cadenas de texto:

```
AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD
AAA.EEE.FFF
AAA.BBB.GGG.FFF
```

Quería convertir esto en un array anidado, en este ejemplo quedaría como así:

```
array(
'AAA' => array(
    'BBB' => array(
        'CCC' => array(
            'DDD'
        ),
        'GGG' => array(
            'FFF'
        ),
    ),
    'EEE' => array(
        'FFF'
    ),
)
);
```

He intentado por JSON, while, for... pero no consigo que funcione.

El largo de las cadenas de texto pueden ser infinito y la longitud de las distintas cadenas de texto no tiene porque ser la misma.

Más información: Es para convertir el listado de buzones devuelto por imap_list a carpetas y subcarpetas.

Gracias :)

Comment: ¿El punto (.) sería el separador?, ¿Que lógica o criterios se usan para determinar la posición de los elementos o en que dimensión debe ir? Puedes agregar el código que has intentado.

Comment: El punto sería el separador. El orden determina el nivel de profundidad en el array, siendo el elemento anterior el padre. Se debería generar dinámicamente pues es el listado de carpetas que devuelve la función imap_list.

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que has intentado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea es acarrear una referencia al subnivel del arreglo mientras se construye:

```
$entradas = array( 'AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD' 
                 , 'AAA.EEE.FFF'
                 , 'AAA.BBB.GGG.FFF'
                 );
$salida = [];
foreach( $entradas as $str ){
   $pedazos = explode('.',$str);
   $nodo = &$salida; // Nodo raíz
   while( $key = array_shift($pedazos) )
      if( empty($pedazos) ) // El último es valor hoja
         $nodo[] = $key;
      else
         $nodo = &$nodo[$key];
}
print_r($salida);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [AAA] => Array
        (
            [BBB] => Array
                (
                    [CCC] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => DDD
                        )
                    [GGG] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => FFF
                        )
                )
            [EEE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => FFF
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Gracias :) También lo conseguí con array_walk